# Calculating Weighted Average for Price and Grouping by Item Type

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in Access that tracks prices for certain products for each store. The table looks like this:

```
Date     | Store   | Item      | SalesPounds | CompanyPrice
1/1/2016 | Store A | Product A | 1,000       | $5.00
1/1/2016 | Store A | Product B | 2,000       | $4.65
1/1/2016 | Store B | Product A | 5,000       | $7.56
1/1/2016 | Store B | Product B | 3,000       | $1.65
```

I would like to calculate the weighted average of `CompanyPrice` and then Group them by the products to look something like this:

```
Date     |Item      | SalesPounds  | CompanyPrice
1/1/2016 | Product A | 6,000        |$7.13
1/1/2016 | Product B | 5,000        |$2.85
```

The query I am currently using is

```
SELECT [Date], [Item], Sum([SalesPounds]) as SumOfPounds, Sum([CompanyPrice]) as SumOfPrice
FROM MyTableName
GROUP BY [Date], [Item];
```

Comment: Note the edits that I made to the question.  Stack Overflow supports easy formatting of code and tables, without the use of HTML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should calculate the weighted average:

```
SELECT [Date],
       Sum([SalesPounds]*[CompanyPrice]) / Sum([SalesPounds]) as WeightedAvg
FROM MyTableName
GROUP BY [Date];
```